# No schemata were loaded : Please check your connection settings, and whether your database (and your database version!) is really supported by jOOQ

Tags: jooq

I use **jooq-codegen-maven** version <3.10.5>

It works with Postgresql 10.4 but doesn't work with PostgreSQL 9.4.6 gives warning:

```
[WARNING] No schemata were loaded  : Please check your connection settings, and whether your database (and your database version!) is really supported by jOOQ. Also, check the case-sensitivity in your configured <inputSchema/> elements : {=[schema_name]}
```

Is there a compatibility table for jooq(code generator) and db versions?

My plugin configuration is:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
    <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
    <version>3.10.5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901.jdbc3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <configuration>
        <!-- JDBC connection parameters -->
        <jdbc>
            <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
            <url>jdbc:postgresql://X.X.X.106:5432/postgres</url>
            <user>xxxx</user>
            <password>xxxx</password>
        </jdbc>
        <!-- Generator parameters -->
        <generator>
            <name>org.jooq.util.DefaultGenerator</name>
            <database>
                <name>org.jooq.util.postgres.PostgresDatabase</name>
                <includes>.*</includes>
                <inputSchema>somedata</inputSchema>
                <excludes></excludes>
            </database>
            <target>
                <packageName>com.xxxx.xxxx.jooq.generated</packageName>
                <directory>target/generated-sources/jooq</directory>
            </target>
        </generator>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Can you provide your complete plugin configuration?

Comment: I edited the post and added the plugin configuration.

Comment: Actually while copying and pasting the configuration file I realize the reason. That was because of the jdbc url; db information part must be different for my new database. Thanks.

Comment: And the JDBC driver! The one you're using is from 2011...

Comment: I found this JDBC driver version by try&fail. Because another problem was occurring related Hikari with newer version of JDBC driver.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error when I copy pasted the pom.xml plugin configuration from jooq website. Later I changed inputSchema in the pom.xml to the name of the database I created (It was 'public' ) before and it generated the code

I changed

```
<inputSchema>public</inputSchema>
```

to

```
<inputSchema>library</inputSchema>
```

where 'library' is the name of the database I created

Answer (score 0):

In my case jdbc url's db part(jdbc:postgresql://X.X.X.106:5432/**postgres**) was wrong for my new database. So changing it with the right one solved my issue.